# Moment JS showing 1 hour of difference in some PC

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, localtime

I dont know why, but in some PCs the momentjs show a wrong time. I belive this caused by daylight summer (current here in my country). But in a few PCs show correctly and anothers with 1 hour of difference (like this print screen).
Apparently  the configuration of all PCs that I test are equals.

[image: momentJS website]

Updating:
In a new check, I see that firefox x chrome are showing differents times. Seems the problem is just in Chrome.

[image: Chrome x Firefox Time]

On windows registry the values HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation are:

[image: regedit print]

**HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Times Zones doesn't exists on my Registry.**

The Chrome navigator.userAgent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.80 Safari/537.36

The  Firefox  navigator.userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0

.

Comment: It would be more helpful to show what code you are running, rather than the screenshot.  Also it would be helpful if you told us what the time zone settings of the computer are.  Type `tzutil /g` on the command line.  Also while on this page, hit F12 in Chrome and type `moment().format()` in the dev console.  Also type `new Date().toString()`.  Put all those values in your question.

Comment: seems timezone configuration in the regional settings, hours is relative...
the regional settings not....
Try a live linux...and same hour..show up in all PC...

Comment: @Sk. tks for your replay.  The timezone is equals in all PCs, but the hour has difference.

Comment: @MattJohnson tks for your repply, I'm using windows server, but will put the console commands on question. tks

Comment: @MattJohnson the chrome console is not working too. I belive some is bloking. tks

Comment: What does `tzutil /g` return on the Windows command line?

Comment: @MattJohnson E. South America Stantard Time. The some in a both PCs.  I Belive that the PC are wrong  is sync time from a server. I sent a msg to administrator of the server. Because the PC are showing correctly is in another network. All PC in this network is showing incorrectly.

Comment: Try changing the time zone to something else, then change it back.  Also make sure automatic DST is enabled.  Then close and reopen Chrome and try again.  LMK if that works for you and I'll explain further.

Comment: @MattJohnson thanks for your support. Please look what I found (picture on ask). Chrome vs. Firefox is displaying a different time.

Comment: Are you sure that `tzutil /g` didn't say `"E. South America Standard Time_dstoff"` on the affected computers?  If DST is off, you may experience these things.  Perhaps the time zone is simply set incorrectly?  What part of Brazil are these computers in?

Comment: @MattJohnson, tks again for help-me. I updated the print screen with this information that you said. tzutil return South America Standard without Time_dstoff but, on windows configuration DST seems is ON. In Brazil I'm  in UTC -3 (with DST ON then in this period UTC -2). In amost Timezone list, the my timezone you will see Brasilia or San Paolo (the both  be official time brazilian)

Comment: @MattJohnson, tks again for help-me. I updated the print screen with this information that you said. tzutil return South America Standard without Time_dstoff but, on windows configuration DST seems is ON. In Brazil I'm in UTC -3 (with DST ON then in this period UTC -2). In amost Timezone list, the my timezone you will see Brasilia or San Paolo (the both are official time brazilian)

Comment: Sorry to keep asking more questions, but can you please give one more screenshot? Open `regedit.exe` and navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation`, and screenshot all of the values in the right-hand pane.  Separately, please tell me the value of the `TzVersion` in the key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`, and also the version of Chrom, as reported either in the Help/About dialog, or by `navigator.userAgent` on the dev console.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MattJohnson, I updated the question with this information. Thank you so much for helping me with this. I believe finding this details on the web would be almost impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for providing all of the information in the question.  Though, I'll say that in retrospect, this isn't really [on topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and would probably fit better on the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) sites in the StackExchange network.  Still, I think I can address your problem:

The main cause is what you wrote:

> `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Times Zones` doesn't exists on my Registry.

That means that somehow, for some reason, perhaps by some other piece of software or perhaps by a system administrator, **that very important key has been deleted**.  That particular key is the root of the Windows time zone database, and contains "Dynamic DST" information - allowing the start and end of DST to vary from year to year.  It is what allows a list of time zones to appear in the control panel to pick from.  If indeed this key does not exist, then that list should appear empty.

Why you see Chrome an hour off, is because Chrome is internally taking the `TimeZoneKeyName`, and then trying to find the corresponding entry in time zone database.  If it is found, then it can use the Dynamic DST from there to ensure that the JS `Date` object behaves correctly with regard to year-over-year changes.

The interesting part is when it is *not* found (because it's deleted on your machine), then Chrome doesn't apply the current year DST information that is in the keys that *are* present on your machine.  It just assumes there is no DST.  FireFox, on the other hand, appears to be falling back to use the current year DST information when the time zone database is missing.

Either way - you're dealing with undocumented behaviors because it is not a reasonable state for your computer to have that key deleted.  There are lots of other things that won't necessarily work correctly (such as scheduling Outlook meetings with people in other time zones, for example).

Additionally, it appears from the screenshot of your registry, that the `DaylightStart` value is the one from 2017, when DST would start in October in Brazil.  It now starts in November, so `00 00 0a 00` should be `00 00 0b 00` at the start of that value.  This change was made in Windows with [KB4093753](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4093753), which doesn't appear to be present on your computer.  This tells me that Windows Updates are not running on these computers. 
 Perhaps your administrator is manually picking which updates to install, or perhaps they have not been updated at all.

With particular regard to time zones, understand that changes are unpredictable.  The various governments around the world can and do change their time zone information, sometimes responsibly, sometimes haphazardly.  Microsoft tracks changes to this data and produces updates for Windows accordingly.  You can review these updates on [the Microsoft TZ/DST blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dst2007/), or in the "Updates that have been issued" section of [KB914387](https://support.microsoft.com/help/914387).  If you don't stay up to date, then you risk not having accurate time zone information.  And if you delete the time zone registry keys as seen here, then all bets are off.

Also note that it's important to have current time zone information even for countries other than your own.  Perhaps, for example, you may need to schedule a meeting with a person in another time zone.  If your computer is not current with time zone data updates, then you may schedule that meeting incorrectly.

At this point, I would recommend installing the latest time zone update (regardless of country indicated) which is [KB4468323](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4468323) at time of writing this.  Time zone updates are cumulative, so in theory installing this update should restore your missing registry key and fix the problem.

Alternatively, and probably better, just turn back on Windows Update.  There are probably many, many more updates you are missing also.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help and for spending your time with my problem. In addition to clarifying my difficulty I also learned a lot of new things. Thanks!

Comment: Initially I did not find the problem was in my operating system, but even if I knew I would not have asked in SuperUser or ServerFault because I did not know those sites. Thank you for introducing me to these other two sites, I will be attentive in the next few times to ask in the most correct place.

Comment: Note that the correct full path to the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones, at least on my operating system.

Comment: Ah, copy paste error I think.  I had the key correct in the original comment.  I'll update the answer, but now I wonder if Márcio actually has the data or not?  @Márcio, look under `Windows NT`, not `Windows`.

Comment: Hi, @MattJohnson, how you helped me to identify that the problem was Windows configuration, I informed the support of that  server and they  (not me)  updated the Windows and the problem was solved.

Comment: This problem originaly was in Windows Server 2012. Also happened on my PC (Windows 7) because of this, some "prints" was from Windows 7 too. In both cases updating the Windows solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you use moment().isDST() and act accordingly...

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-daylight-saving-time/

Comment: Tks @Marcus, I will test this.

Comment: Hi @MarcusSabino, on Chrome moment().isDST() result false. On Firefox  moment is not defined.